# Google Analytics on Flex IFrames

Tags: apache-flex, iframe, google-analytics, tracking

So I would like to include pageTracker code in the iFrames that is being called.

However the iFrames in this case are called from Flex. We are building a pop up and calling the iframes within the pop up.

In this scenario, what is the best way to include the pageTracker code to track and trasnfer the visitor and campaign cookies from one domain to the next?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Flex-IFrame](http://code.google.com/p/flex-iframe/), you can use the [callIFrameFunction](http://flex-iframe.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flexiframe/doc/com/google/code/flexiframe/IFrame.html#callIFrameFunction()) to insert the Javascript code you need.